# How to avoid putting a password in declarative html/angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, security

I have a custom angular directive that takes a password value from the declarative html and uses it to connect to a third party service.  Is there a way I can more readily secure the username and password so that anyone looking at the html can't just see the username and password in plain text?  Is there a way to "encode" the html markup for that directive?  What is the best practice for securing passwords in this situation?  It is not a password that a user of the application would know, it is a password used by the application itself to connect to a third party tool.

Comment: You can't secure secrets in a pure client app. I mean, you can make it harder to find it, but any half-decent developer-user could get it any way. If you are using something like OAuth, then the secret should be on the server, and the client could just get an access token

Comment: Does the third party service not have OAuth or similar? If not, you can reverse proxy through your server and store the password on your server.

Comment: The third party service does have oAuth, and the username and password in the html markup is used to get a token that is used to access other secured resources on the server.  But I still have the username and password in plain text in the html markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that in a client-side application. Even if you encrypt the access credentials, some portion of your code will still have to decrypt them, meaning that the user can easily invoke that code manually and grab the values.

In fact, depending on how your application connects to the 3rd party service, the user may not need to do anything at all. The decrypted values would probably show up in the browser's network inspector.